# Check if Facebook User is streaming live, then embed their live stream?

Tags: facebook

Is there a way through the facebook API to check if a user is live streaming?

Then if they are, get the embed code for their live stream so I can put it on my own website?

Answer (score 3):

You can query /me/live_videos according to https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/live_videos/

Comment: How does this work? I am trying to do it using the api explorer but I just get permission errors: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/145634995501895/?method=GET&path=524730693%2Flive_videos&version=v2.6

Comment: Read the documentation for what permission is needed

Comment: I literally gave my access token every permission... still gives permission errors.